# DotNetNuke - Everytime a third party DLL is modified in the BIN folder, it takes DNN 10 seconds to load the next page

Tags: iis, dotnetnuke

I have a standard DotNetNuke installation that I am developing some modules for.

Every time I update one of my modules, it updates that module's DLL in the DotNetNuke installation's bin folder.

Despite the fact that I am not touching the main DotNetNuke DLL, it seems that IIS is either reprocessing every DLL in the folder, or doing some other majorly time consuming task because it is taking at least 10 seconds to load any page after I recompile the single module's DLL.

For comparison, if this module were running outside of DotNetNuke, it would load in under a second.

Is there some way to get around this delay?

Comment: I'm pretty certain that this is asp.net recompiling your site.  You could precompile it in that case, but then updates are to the whole site, not one module.

Comment: Why would the whole site need to be recompiled? I'm precompiling in Visual Studio as far as I can tell (DLL is generated and put into the DNN bin folder everytime I compile)

Comment: If you change a dll, how is the runtime supposed to know one of your pages isn't broken unless it recompiles them? `p.s.` I'm not talking about the compilation of your dlls.  That doesn't include the pages getting compiled, which happens when the first request is received.

Comment: Wow, I kinda thought the whole point of compiling into DLL's was so that they whole thing didn't have to be recompiled. Since I'm not touching the actual DNN DLL's, is there some way to avoid this 10+ second recompilation period? I mean.. should I manually compile them from VStudio or something? I don't even have the source. Thanks

Comment: I will add some links about it, including about precompilation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever you change a .dll in the bin folder ASP.Net will restart the application.  Application startup does not necessarily mean anything gets recompiled, though some of the modules may get recompiled, but probably not until they are used.  A bunch of the time goes into inspecting/loading all of the assemblies in the bin folder, and executing all the application startup code.  Removing any unneeded modules will help reduce the start up time, as those assemblies will no longer need to be loaded.

Mitchell Sellers has a great document titled DotNetNuke Performance Configuration Best Practices [download here](http://www.iowacomputergurus.com/white-papers.aspx) several of the recommendations will help reduce startup time, and it is a generally a good reference on how to effectively deploy a DNN site.

Answer (score 1):

Per comments, it sounds like the usual Asp.net site compile happening.  Here are some good links covering the details.

[msdn: ASP.NET Compilation Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178466.aspx)
[msdn: ASP.NET Web Site Precompilation Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/399f057w(VS.85).aspx) 
[Rick Stahl has a good write up](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/AspNetCompilation/AspNetCompilation.asp)